# Returning error text from QgsProcessingFeedback

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have a snippet that intersects two map layers (`blockLayer`  and `ogLayer`) in QGIS; and prints out when a bad geometry prevents the intersection from occurring. It builds a subclass from `QgsProcessingFeedback`, based on the answer posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310787/getting-log-message-from-qgis-processing-framework) by [@ndawson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/28443/ndawson).

Here's the code:

```
class MyFeedBack(QgsProcessingFeedback): # create a subclass from the QgsProcessingFeedback class
    def reportError(self, error, fatalError=False): # QgsProcessingFeedback.reportError() is a method 
        if "invalid geometry" in error:
            featNum = error.split("(")[1].split(")")[0]
            print("{} has bad geometry".format(featNum))
            
blockLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("harvestApprovals")[0]
ogLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Boundary old growth .gdb layer')[0]

#feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback.reportError(self, error, fatalError=False)
#feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback.reportError(error, fatalError=False)

feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback() # instantitate the QgsProcessingFeedback class
print(feedback)

params = {'INPUT':blockLayer,'OVERLAY':ogLayer,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}
rslt = processing.run("native:intersection", params, feedback=MyFeedBack())

print("\nDone!")
```

I'd prefer to create a list to add those numbers to, so as to know which geometries need repair.
I'm just not sure how (or if it's possible) to build a list within an instance of a class, and somehow return that list from the class.

Is there some way I could `myList.append(featNum)` as the errors are encountered, then get `myList` back after the process has run?

Answer (score 3):

When I run your script, `print` statement never run although I get an error. Thus, I couldn't test it. But the following way should work for you.

- Add a variable (`myList = []`) to root scope.
- Use it in `reportError` method with `global` keyword.

```py
myList = []

class MyFeedBack(QgsProcessingFeedback): 
    def reportError(self, error, fatalError=False): 
        if "invalid geometry" in error:
            featNum = error.split("(")[1].split(")")[0]

            global myList
            myList.append(featNum)

#
# other lines
#

print(myList)
print("\nDone!")
```