# 'reportError' in subclass of QgsProcessingFeedback never running

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, error

I have two layers, `layer_a` and `layer_b`. Both have invalid geometries. When I run a processing tool, it throws an error as expected.

Based on the answer posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310787/getting-log-message-from-qgis-processing-framework) by [@ndawson](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/28443/ndawson), if you subclass `QgsProcessingFeedback`, you can implement your own custom logic dealing with the error.

> ```
> class MyFeedBack(QgsProcessingFeedback):
>
>     def reportError(self, error, fatalError=False):
>         print(error)
>
> ...
>
> res = processing.run("TOOL_NAME", params, feedback=MyFeedBack())
> ```

When I run the following script in QGIS Python Editor

```
class MyFeedBack(QgsProcessingFeedback): 
    def reportError(self, error, fatalError=False): 
        print("ERROR! ERROR!")
            
layer_a = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("a")[0]
layer_b = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('b')[0]

feedback = MyFeedBack()

params = {'INPUT': layer_a, 'OVERLAY': layer_b, 'OUTPUT': 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'}
rslt = processing.run("native:intersection", params, feedback=feedback)

print("\nDone!")
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py", line 108, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py", line 159, in runAlgorithm
    ret, results = execute(alg, parameters, context, feedback, catch_exceptions=False)
  File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/gui/AlgorithmExecutor.py", line 71, in execute
    results, ok = alg.run(parameters, context, feedback, {}, False)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Feature (0) from “b” has invalid geometry. Please fix the geometry or change the Processing setting to the “Ignore invalid input features” option.
```

According to [documentation](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingFeedback.html#ad1c14839a74c2ef1a5caef4b57a638b9), `reportError` method should run in case of any error. But the method never runs although the processing tool throws an error.

What am I doing wrong?

I use
QGIS 3.16.2-Hannover, Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
QGIS 3.16.0-Hannover, Windows 10 x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the lines between 61 and 71 of the [algorithmExecutor](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/gui/AlgorithmExecutor.py#L61), you can see that there is a condition with the `catch_exceptions` test.
For some reasons, in the `runAlgorithm` of Processing.py the `catch_exceptions` is set to `False`. So the error is never transmitted by the `reportError` method (line 68)

So you could submit an issue to ask if it's normal. To me, it seems like a bug.

EDIT : According to core dev, it's not. See his response : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/40978